# Two players game - how to match them using database?

Tags: algorithm

I'm developing a simple game program. This game is web based and two players play each other. Now I need to match the player randomly. The method I used was as below.

Player comes in
-> put the user in the db with availability of 1 and pair status 0.
-> As more players comes in, db has many players who want to be matched.
-> So the player gets the array of the other player IDs' and randomly choose one
-> Then put the ID as an opponent.
-> Change availability to 0 and pair status 1.

So the problem here is, sometimes 2 players get the same ID(same opponent). So I'm really looking for the way to solve this problem.

My thinking is that I make temporary opponent and check if the players have them each other correctly, and then put it as an actual opponent. If they don't have the their own names as a temporary opponent, then remove the temp opponent and keep looking for a player to match.

I was trying to be descriptive about the problem that I'm having. Any idea would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: lock your db table when you are matching players

Comment: No I have not solved this problem. I think basically I want to know how to connect two players online. Since I'm using db(mysql) to connect them, it creates many problems.

Answer (score 0):

Depends mostly on the way the matching of players is implemented, but you need to make sure you only assign two players if they have not been assigned yet, and only use each ID once.

Are there multiple processes doing the matching?

Comment: No. There is only one process doing the matching which has the server. I also read that when I do 'ALTER TABLE...' mysql locks the table temporarily as the access is for read only. I guess I should try to use temp and actual method to double check before assigning?

Comment: @Jules Can you add the actual SQL query to your question? With only one process assigning the ID's there could be an error in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a transaction. Set the availability of the opponent to 0 and create a game row. After it has been created, check whether the opponent already plays another game and if so, roll back.